# Writing a linked list code with 3D head

Tags: linked-list, fortran

I'm trying to write a linked list code with 3D head. hear is what I tried:

```
SUBROUTINE cell_list (rat,nat,cell,nx,ny,nz,hx,hy,hz,link)

USE constants
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: nat
REAL(8) :: rat(3,nat)
INTEGER,intent(inout) :: nx,ny,nz !number of cells per dimension
REAL(8),intent(inout) :: hx,hy,hz !size of a cell
REAL(8) :: Lx,Ly,Lz !length of the box
REAL(8) :: xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,zmin,zmax
INTEGER :: iat !label of particles
INTEGER :: j,k !loop control
INTEGER :: cellx,celly,cellz !id of the cell for certain atom
INTEGER :: link(nat)
INTEGER :: cell(1:nx,1:ny,1:nz)

cell = 0
link = 0
DO iat = 1,nat
    cellx = int(rat(1,iat)/hx)+1
    celly = int(rat(2,iat)/hy)+1
    cellz = int(rat(3,iat)/hz)+1    
    if (cell(cellx,celly,cellz).ne.0) then
         link(iat) = cell(cellx,celly,cellz)
    endif
    cell(cellx,celly,cellz)=iat    
END DO
END SUBROUTINE cell_list
```

in like `linke(iat)=cell(cellx,celly,cellz)` how do we assign 3D array to  link which is a scalar. Is my code true?
I saw the same code for 1D in some books like "Understanding Molecular simulation, Frenkel" and there he used sth like this:

```
linke(iat)=cell(icell)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the purpose of `link `? And `cell `? Why don't you use pointers?

Comment: To reduce the cpu time for evaluating the interaction between particles. Each particle just see 26 cell around itself. link cennect the particles in each cell. This structure is used in molecular dynamics.

Comment: Be more specific, what do the variables mean?

Comment: @ Vladimir :Thank you, but solved. I checked the code with some data. it's true.

Comment: To speed up force calculation, a cell list is implemented. First the simulation volume is divided
to smaller cells with size equal to or slightly larger than the cut-off radius. Then a cell list is built
up that contains the labels of the atoms that are in certain cell. The basic data structure used in
my program is a link list. The link list consists of two matrices: cell and link. Each cell has a
corresponding link list that stores the information of what atoms are located in this cell, the
head of which is stored in the matrix cell,

Comment: while the label of the next atom in the link list is
stored in the matrix link. All elements of the cell matrix are initialized to zero. Then scan all the
atoms, locate them to certain cell, and insert the atom into the link list of the corresponding cell
that it belongs to, which follows the standard routine of operations on a link list.